# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot connect to a particular network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, 64-bit

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit on Dell Latıtude E5440 and it is not able to connect to the network inside the university campus although I provide the correct settings which are as follows:

1. Security type: WPA2-Enterprıse
2. Encryption type: AES
3. Network Authentication Method: Microsoft:Protected EAP(PEAP)
4. Authentication Method: EAP-MSCHAP v2

I have no certificate and I use my student credentials to log into the network on other OS. When I try to connect to this particular network on Ubuntu I am asked for the certificate and the credentials endless times. The settings windows in Windows 7 are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have a similar campus wireless network and it has the same settings as you mentioned above. Please click the configure button beside the "choose a network authentication method" section and uncheck "Automatic Windows logon" and click "OK". Now you may try to connect to the network.